# psycopg2 error say i am inserting integer when i am inserting text/ string

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, psql

when I run this query from my python app

```
DB.execute("insert into matches values(%s ,%s, %s, %s)", (player1, player2, player1_result, player2_result,))
```

I get this error

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "win"
LINE 1: insert into matches values(689 ,690, 'win', 'lose')
                                             ^
```

player1, player2, player1_result and player2_result are arguments given to the containing function here

```
reportMatch(id1, id2, "win", "lose")
```

here is the table definition

```
create table matches ( player1 serial references players, player2 serial references players, player1_result text, player2_result text, match_ID serial primary key);
```

Comment: First, try listing the columns out explicitly in the `insert` statement.

Comment: oh if you mean listing them by querying them, I can't because the table is empty

Comment: No, I mean using `insert into matches(player1, player2, player1_result, player2_result) . . . `  When using `insert`, you should almost always include the explicit list of columns.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't actually know how to do that. However, I just solved my problem and  the problem was that "win" was being inserted in to 'player2' because the 'player1' argument was being inserted in to the 'match_ID' column due to not explicitly stating which columns the values should be inserted in to. I thought that nothing COULD be inserted in to a serial column.

Can you tell me how to explicitly state the columns in my insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query is:

```
insert into matches
    values(%s ,%s, %s, %s)
```

(and then the values)

This is bad form, because the order of insertion depends on the order of declaration of the columns.

When using `insert`, you should explicitly list the columns, so the SQL looks like:

```
insert into matches(player1, player2, player1_result, player2_result)
    values(%s ,%s, %s, %s)
```

In your statement, this is:

```
DB.execute("insert into matches(player1, player2, player1_result, player2_result) values(%s ,%s, %s, %s)", (player1, player2, player1_result, player2_result))
```